# Ubuntu Kylin stuck at blue welcome screen

Tags: boot, live-usb, kylin

Recently I had installed Ubuntu Kylin on a 32GB USB hard disk (The internal one is not an option currently), and after installing it I am presented with an unchanging "Ubuntu Kylin" blue welcome screen:

[image]

What do I do? If you have any questions please ask!